# PL/SQL ¿Cuándo usar funciones y cuándo procedimientos?

Tags: oracle, funciones, stored-procedure, oracle-11g, plsql

El día de hoy me encuentro con una inquietud que por mas que he consultado por Internet aun no me queda del todo claro y es saber.

¿En qué momento se debe usar una función y cuándo se debe usar un procedimiento en ORACLE PL/SQL?.

Les agradecería una respuesta con su respectivo soporte y/o explicación.

Comment: ¿Pudiste comprobar mi respuesta? ¿Te fue de ayuda? ¿Te queda alguna duda más que pudiera aclarar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una vez que entiendas estas diferencias tú mismo podrás decidir en qué momento usar una u otra.

Características:

- Un procedimiento no puede devolver un valor, una función sí (aunque ambos puedan devolver datos en parámetros `OUT` e `IN OUT`, [ver ejemplos](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/129-Use-of-OUT-and-INOUT-Parameters.html) aunque sean para postgres).
- De lo anterior podemos deducir que las funciones se usan como parte de una expresión (`campo1 * MIFUNCION(campo2)`), los procedimientos no.
- La instrucción `return` devuelve el control al programa que la llama y entrega los resultados en ella, en el procedimiento devuelve el control al programa que la llamó pero no devuelve un valor.
- Las funciones pueden ser llamadas desde instrucciones SQL (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc) y los procedimientos no (deben ser llamados de manera independiente).

Dependiendo del uso que quieras darle tú mismo te darás cuenta cual se adapta mejor a tus necesidades.

Usos comunes:

- Procedimientos: Ejecutar una serie de consultas, modificaciones en diferentes tablas o cálculos entre ellas que serían complejas en una única instrucción SQL y no requiere de un valor de retorno.
- Funciones: Cálculo de un valor que será usado en una consulta SQL (como campo de un resultado `SELECT`, asignación de valor en un `UPDATE` o como filtro en un `WHERE`) a partir de parámetros de entrada, ya sea accediendo a datos de diferentes tablas o bien a partir únicamente de los parámetros de entrada.

Answer (score 0):

un procedimiento no devuelve valor y debe ser usado dentro de un bloque pl/sql o dentro de otro procedimiento o función.
una función devuelve un valor (return) y se usa se puede usar también dentro de un procedimiento o función pero asignando su resultado a una variable o dentro de una expreción aritmética, logica de cadena, etc. las funciones también pueden ser usadas dentro de una consulta SQL, aunque hay que tener en cuenta que en estos casos no deben estar usando sentencias de actualización de tablas (INSER, DELETE o UPDATE)

Answer (score 0):

A mi me agrada mucho usar las funciones como si fuesen procedimiento,ahorro lineas de código.

dentro del PKG:

```
ERR_FUN_NOM_FUN  EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
.
.
.
If (fun_nom_fun(p1,p2,pn)= FALSE) then  /* LA FUNCION RETORNA BOOLEAN */
   mensaje de Error; -- o accion de control de error RAISE ERR_FUN_NOM_FUN;
End if;
.
.
.
exception
  when ERR_FUN_NOM_FUN then
     mensaje error;
  when others then
     mensaje error;
END;
```

Comment: por favor lee [answer] pues no es solo poner código sino explicarlo

Comment: esta respuesta no solo le debe servir a quien preguntó sino al resto de comunidad